# Hide text completely if it overflows with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to hide text completely if it overflows.
`overflow: hidden` won't work for me here, because it will cut off the text.

I would like to use something that "detects" if the text is cut off, and if so it should be removed or not displayed. In this case only one word (or if you want so the word that would get cut).

A pure CSS solution if this is possible would be great. If there is no other way, JS would also be kind of ok.

For my example see the following images. The arrow is inserted by a pseudo class `::before`

*How it looks when it's fully displayed*

[image: How it looks when it's]

*How it looks like now when it overflows*

[image: How it looks like now when it overflows]

*What I want it to look like when it overflows*

[image: What I want it to look like when it overflows]

```css
.somediv {
  width: 100%;
}

.somediv_2 {
  width: 20px;
}

.someanchor {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  padding: .125rem .625rem .125rem .625rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.someanchor::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f0d7";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv">
  <a class="someanchor">
        Info
      </a>
</div>


<div class="somediv_2">
  <a class="someanchor">
        Info
      </a>
</div>
```

I made the second button smaller to simulate it. In my case it gets smaller by resizing the viewport, because it's pushed by other elements in a table.

Comment: If you can specify a fixed _height_ for the element - then you could remove `white-space: nowrap`, and it would make the text break into a second row, if there is not enough place for it to go next to the arrow … and because overflow is hidden, it would disappear then. If that is not possible - then you will likely have to measure the text width using JavaScript.

Comment: It's unclear if this would have a knock-on effect: if you set `white-space:auto;max-height:1.75rem;` (with your existing `overflow:hidden`) you get "vertical clipping"

Comment: @CBroe That kind of works. The "Info" is gone, but the box is still as big as if there is more text. It doesn't resize to the size of the arrow

Comment: @freedomn-m As far as I see `white-space: auto;` doesn't exist. At least devtools tell me that it's invalid.

Comment: _“It doesn't resize to the size of the arrow”_ – I don’t think that will be possible using CSS alone.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, I tried all kind of things. `max-width` `min-width`. For now my workaround is to just center the arrow so it's not that annoying.

Comment: @jona correct, my mistake, by setting to an invalid value it reverted to default `normal` or not-applied/inherit, so it's the same as removing it.